# Function class javascript not finding variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript docs on my project.
js (script.js) #1:

```
let func = new Function('return thisvar')
console.log(func())
```

js (script1.js) #2:

```
let thisvar = 'hello'
```

I get an error:
`ERROR:{@script.js line 4: cannot find variable 'thisvar'}`
I have tried using var instead of let or even window.thisvar
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use window. Then the return should be `window.thisvar` not `thisvar`

Comment: Can I avoid using window?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Of course, you need to export the variable and import in the file you want to use it

Comment: Well that's interesting, wasn't aware that we can define functions with this syntax.

Comment: Which file are you loading first? script #2 or script #1?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `func()` in your first script, you haven't yet defined `thisvar`.

Just move the function call to your second script after you define the variable.

```js
let func = new Function('return thisvar')
```

```js
let thisvar = 'hello'
console.log(func())
```

Comment: Is there another way? I want the function deceleration in the file with the running of the function

Comment: You could (if you have a really good reason to) assign `thisvar` to the global context. In a browser that is `window`. So would do `window.thisvar = 'hello'`.

I wouldn't recommend this, but for learning purposes, it should be fine.

Comment: @JSst67 you could just switch the order of the scripts if you want

Comment: @Y.Gherbi that wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: @skara9 What do you mean? Could you please explain why this wouldn't solve the problem?

Comment: @Y.Gherbi regardless if you attach the variable to the window or not, it still won't be defined at the time of the execution of the function

Comment: @skara9 oh I see, my bad! The function is declared before. Changing the order should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Readable "hello world" example (The `console.log(func(your_error)` return the same error - cannot find variable (You didn't declare the variable).

```html
<span>example</span>
<script>
      let func = new Function("arg1", "return arg1")

      let thisvar = 'hello'; /* missing in your code */
      console.log(func(thisvar))
      // expected output: hello
      console.log(func("world"))
      // expected output: world
      console.log(func(your_error))
      // expected output: "Uncaught ReferenceError: your_error is not defined"
 </script>
```

In general it is more efficient to use [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) or [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

Comment: The other answer will work but I personally think this one would help you more @JSst67

Comment: I can import and export using `window.item = item` so I’m hoping to use that for the Function class. Also, I am creating a library that needs to access another script’s variable.

Comment: The route goes like this: FROM commandLine TO library.js: 5+thisvar

Comment: library.js does Function class request: "return 5+thisvar" and user.js has thisvar as a variable.